# How to change iphone CATiledLayer fadeDuration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I am working on an iphone application that displays tiled maps. I am currently using a CATiledLayer in a UIScrollView :

```
     MyTiledDelegate *delegate=[[MyTiledDelegate alloc] initWithMapLayer:map];
     tileLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
     tileLayer.delegate = delegate;
     [scrollView.layer addSublayer:tileLayer];
     [tileLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

I wrote and set my own delegate which implements the draw layer method like so :

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
    CGRect rect =CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx);
    CGFloat x = fabs(round(rect.origin.x/tileSize));
    CGFloat y = fabs(round(rect.origin.y/tileSize));

    Tile *tile = [map getTileForMapZoom:z x:x y:y];
    CGImageRef img=[tile getRealImage];
    CGContextDrawImage(
        ctx,
        CGRectMake(tile.x*tileSize,tile.y*tileSize, tileSize,tileSize) , 
        img);
    }//edited for brevity
```

I am annoyed by the default behavior of the CAtiledLayer to fadein after the tile is drawn. Also, sometimes the fadein is not complete (it stops at 90 or 95% opacity).

**How can i change or (preferably) remove the fadein animation ?**

I played with the `speed` and `duration` properties of my CATiledLayer instance, to no avail. I don't set any animation on the tiledLayer. the `[tiledLayer removeAllAnimation]` does not change anything either.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: fade duration defaults to 0.25 if no duration is set or is set to a negative number.  there doesn't seem to be anyway I can find to *not* fade.

Comment: Hi everybody. Thank you for your answers. They fix the problem. I had though of overriding in a subclass, but hoped that there was a more elegant way that didn't involve creating yet another class. I guess i will make the CATiledLayer delegate subclass the CATiledLAyer. Thanks again.

Comment: hi nico_h
can you plesae tell me how you fixed your problem. i am also facing same issue. how you achieved this without using subclass?

Comment: As described in the answer I accepted bellow, I had to subclass the CATiledLayer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should subclass the CATiledLayer and return fadeDuration of 0 to disable fade-in:

```
@interface FastCATiledLayer : CATiledLayer
@end

@implementation FastCATiledLayer
+(CFTimeInterval)fadeDuration {
  return 0.0;
}
@end
```

I also had the problem with fade in animation not completing, what helped was to set the background color of the view to `[UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Make sure to replace `fastDuration` with `fadeDuration` in the code.

Comment: The "not completion" problem appeared to go away when I set the fadeDuration to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try subclassing and overriding the `+fadeDuration` accessor on the layer.

Answer (score 0):

Or in Swift 4:

```
class CAFastTiledLayer: CATiledLayer {
    class func fadeDuration() -> CFTimeInterval {
        return 0.0 
    }
}
```