# Basic implementation of CATiledLayer flashing

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uipangesturerecognizer, catiledlayer

Because zoomed-in scroll view’s content was fuzzy, I implemented `CATiledLayer` as [this](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_zooming_with_detail) article recommends. I made  basic implementation like [here](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/presentation-120225213706-phpapp02/95/implementing-catiledlayer-14-728.jpg?cb=1330228221) I found.

Edges become more smooth, but when I moving views with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, content starts flashing. Any idea how to fix?

**How can I trigger to redraw layer, but without let it flashing?**
I guess neither `v.setNeedsDisplay()` nor `(v.layer as! CATiledLayer).setNeedsDisplay()`
is the right way in this case. Both of the are flashing.

This is the basic implementation what I have added:

```
class RelationshipView: UIView {

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CATiledLayer.self
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        (self.layer as! CATiledLayer).levelsOfDetail = 1
        (self.layer as! CATiledLayer).levelsOfDetailBias = 3
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
```

## UPDATE

Meantime I have subclassed `CATiledLayer` and using `FastCATiledLayer` with 0.0 `fadeDuration` return value instead of `CATiledLayer` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073727/how-to-change-iphone-catiledlayer-fadeduration). But still flashing.

```
class FastCATiledLayer: CATiledLayer {

    override class func fadeDuration() -> CFTimeInterval {
        return 0.0
    }

    override func actionForKey(event: String!) -> CAAction! {

        if event == "contents" {
            return nil
        } else {
            return super.actionForKey(event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the details right now, but IIRC the secret was to override animationForKey: (or whatever that method is called) and return NSNull for the "content" animation.

Comment: with `animationKeys` override it is still flashing

Comment: Ah sorry, it was `actionForKey:` or the delegate method `actionForLayer:forKey:`

Comment: I have added `actionForKey` for `"contents"`, but still flashing

Comment: Can you please upload a project of that, so that we could test it in action?